# Advice : Using java to display changing data in a graphical representation. Easiest Technology To Learn

Tags: java

Good evening,

My current experience is with Java Core and at a junior level so would appreciate a steer on the simplest approach with this.

I am currently using Java to consume and process REST performance data at a 5min polling interval. I would now like to display these various performance metrics in an auto updating graphical form using Java (example : different graphics being displayed representing the various loads on a system).

I have done some reading and at the moment it appears I either

- Start to learn JAVAFX and try and create a desktop application.
- Pick one of the simpler web application frameworks (Java Spark?) but I was not clear on how one would auto update the clients browser without some other client side language.

Any advice on the best way to go for someone with my level of experience would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I would look through the ThoughtWorks Radar for a recommendation.

Comment: This is off topic, but I would suggest vaadin.

Comment: Thanks will take a look at both resources mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is in the same position I would recommend looking into javafx. Took me a few days of playing about but in the end it was relatively straightforward to get a professional looking animated real time graph.